# GEE add a constant median band representing the median of pixels within a multipolygon

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, zonal-statistics, time-series

I have a time series of Sentinel-2 images and I'd like to get a single median EVI index value over a multipolygon representing known land-cover areas in each image and set that as a constant band called "EVI_median" for each image. I am getting stuck with the median calculation itself. I though I could add the new band within the `select` statement?

```
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR");
var geometry = 
    ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(
        [[[[-41.106911963812735, -16.41548768412473],
           [-41.106911963812735, -16.41548768412473],
           [-41.106911963812735, -16.41548768412473],
           [-41.106911963812735, -16.41548768412473]]],
         [[[-41.114121741644766, -16.40659562215289],
           [-41.114121741644766, -16.413347039686705],
           [-41.10553867279711, -16.413347039686705],
           [-41.10553867279711, -16.40659562215289]]],
         [[[-41.08751422821703, -16.41005369454927],
           [-41.08751422821703, -16.414335032354956],
           [-41.08133441864672, -16.414335032354956],
           [-41.08133441864672, -16.41005369454927]]]], null, false);
      
var filter = ee.Filter.and(
    ee.Filter.bounds(geometry), 
    ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01', '2022-01-01'));
    
S2 = S2.filter(filter)
    .map(function (image) {
        var EVI = image.expression(
            '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
            'NIR' : image.select('B8').divide(10000),
            'RED' : image.select('B4').divide(10000),
            'BLUE': image.select('B2').divide(10000)}).rename('EVI');
        return image.addBands(EVI);
      });

var clipped = S2.map(function(image){return image.clip(geometry)});
var s2withMedian = clipped.map(function (image) {
  var median = image.select(['EVI'], ['EVI_median']).median();
  return image.addBands(median);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue with your code is that you should use `reduceRegion` instead of `median` to calculate a single EVI value over a multipolygon. Usually, `median` is used to calculate a median value on the temporal dimension of an `ee.ImageCollection`, resulting in an `ee.Image` object. On the contrary, `reduceRegion` is used to calculate a median value on the spatial dimension of an `ee.Image`, resulting in a `ee.Dictionary` object. Thus, when using `reduceRegion`, you should extract the median value  (`getNumber`) and then create an image with that value using `ee.Image.constant`. Here is the only modification you should make to your code.

```
var s2withMedian = clipped.map(function (image) {
  var median = image.select('EVI')
                    .reduceRegion({
                      reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
                      scale: 10,
                      maxPixels: 1e9
                    }).getNumber('EVI');
  var medianImage = ee.Image.constant(median)
                            .rename('EVI_median')
                            // cast it to same type as EVI band
                            .double();
  return image.addBands(medianImage);
});
```

Comment: Much obliged, Jonathan!  This solution worked like charm. One can start to run circles around a problem when in the weeds.  Thanks for helping me get unstuck!